# How to set map center to a certain city?

Tags: angularjs, cordova, google-maps-api-3, ionic-framework

I have an angular google map in my Ionic application and for the first time it sets the map center to the users geolocation with cordova-plugin-geolocation but in case the user want to see what can the app offer in other cities I'd like to change the map center by letting the user to choose another city from a list. 
What would be the proper way to do this if I don't know the coords of every city?

Comment: Yes get lat/long for cities from list and set that lat/long as map center.

Comment: The list is my own and contains only the city names.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the city coordinates from the Geocoding API, and pass those to your maps.

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/intro

Comment: Thank you Marc you saved me a lot of time! Cheers

Comment: Glad to be of help